# Why are my libraries not being imported into Sonar when using the Ant task?

Tags: ant, sonarqube

We are evaluating Sonar and I've set up an Ant task to import my project data into Sonar using the instructions [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+ANT) but my libraries aren't appearing in the libraries view.

Apart from this it is working as all the other information is there.

Maybe I've misunderstood what the libraries element is for in the Ant task? Please can someone tell me what I'm missing?

[image: Screen shot of Sonar showing empty libraries view]

From my build file:

```
    <target name="sonar">
    <sonar:sonar workDir="sonartemp" key="org.example:example" version="0.1-SNAPSHOT" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">

        <!-- source directories (required) -->
        <sources>
            <path location="src/common/src" />
            <path location="src/commonWidgets/src" />
            <path location="src/compositionWidget/src" />
            <path location="src/nativeLib/src" />
            <path location="src/services/src" />
        </sources>

        <!-- list of properties (optional) -->
        <property key="sonar.projectName" value="Test RPS Composition Import" />
        <property key="sonar.dynamicAnalysis" value="true" />

            <!-- test source directories (optional) -->
            <tests>
            <path location="src/common/test" />
            <path location="src/commonWidgets/test" />
            <path location="src/compositionWidget/test" />
            <path location="src/services/test" />
            </tests>

        <!-- binaries directories, which contain for example the compiled Java bytecode (optional) -->
        <binaries>
            <path location="src/common/build" />
            <path location="src/commonWidgets/build" />
            <path location="src/compositionWidget/build" />
            <path location="src/services/build" />
        </binaries>

        <!-- path to libraries (optional). These libraries are for example used by the Java Findbugs plugin -->
        <libraries>
            <path location="src/common/lib/**/" />
            <path location="src/commonWidgets/lib/**/" />
            <path location="src/compositionWidget/lib/**/" />
            <path location="src/services/lib/" />
        </libraries>
    </sonar:sonar>
</target>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this view only works with maven.
The libraries in the ant task definition are for the static analysis tools like findbugs.

This tab is information only and not needed for anything.

Comment: What about gradle java build? For me, libraries tab is empty too.